# htaccess URL rewrite file treat as folder?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Are there any possibility to rewrite URL with page `http://welcome.com/about.php` into something like this URL `http://welcome.com/about/`

But already have some rewrite rules :

```
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^view/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)\.html/?$   data_view.php?id=$1&cat=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^data/include/(.+)?  Admin/$1


ErrorDocument 400 /page-not-found
ErrorDocument 401 /page-not-found
ErrorDocument 403 /page-not-found
ErrorDocument 404 /page-not-found
ErrorDocument 500 /page-not-found
```

**UPDATE**

I am looking 
`http://welcome.com/about.php?id=12&cat=13`  **into** `http://welcome.com/about/12/13`

Answer (score 0):

Have it like this:

```
ErrorDocument 400 /page-not-found
ErrorDocument 401 /page-not-found
ErrorDocument 403 /page-not-found
ErrorDocument 404 /page-not-found
ErrorDocument 500 /page-not-found

Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^view/(\d+)/(\d+)/([A-Za-z\d-]+)\.html/?$ data_view.php?id=$1&cat=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^data/include/(.*)$ Admin/$1 [L,NC]

# rewrite /about/ or /about to /about.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```